# WPF DataBinding and Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding

I have a WPF User Interface and I've implemented bound ValidationRules with UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit". I'm finding that it works perfectly when I have the tab page where the fields being validated is visible:
[image]

but if I'm on the third tab page where the form ends and trigger the UpdateSources method on the BindingExpressions for the fields being Validated then when I step back to the first tab the fields aren't actually highlighted in red. Even once I'm back on that tab page and re-trigger they don't highlight even though they're empty. I need to enter a value, re-trigger, then delete the value and re-trigger, THEN the modified ones get highlighted.

Anyone know how to address this behaviour? 
Also is there a way to force a specific tab page to be switched to when the Validation fails, switching to the page which has the first field to fail?

I know there's an option to go with PropertyChanged and LostFocus but I'd like to get full form entry first and do all validation in one hit at the end.

Comment: The far better user experience would be to validate on input. The current input field already has the users attention. Allowing him to leave the page suggests that everything is alright. Therefore validation should execute on user input or at least before leaving the page or tab. Bringing or forcing the user back to a page he already left with the feeling "all is well" feels like an interruption. User needs to re-focus and touch every input field again (worst case) which raises annoyance. This will result in a bad experience.

Comment: Implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface in a view model and bind to source properties.

Comment: I think it's actually to do with TabControl and the fact it doesn't retain certain aspects of each page. I'm investigating that now

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way the `TabControl` handles the `AdornerLayer`. They are obviously not preserved when the `TabItem` is switched. It works when you force to re-render the `AdornerLayer` when switching back to the `TabItem`.

```
<!-- Custom error template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplate">
  <StackPanel>

    <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}"
               Foreground="Red" />
  </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Style to trigger the rendering of the AdornerLayer by setting the error template -->
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
          Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Validation.HasError"
                   Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsVisible"
                   Value="True" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
              Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Consider to disallow leaving the current tab if it has validation errors to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Ah thanks! I’ve already solved the issue with a subclass TabControlEx which forces caching the pages of the tab control although it’s a fairly heavyweight change and o don’t have list items which are what the author said tend to not rebind. This solution you’ve provided might be preferably as it’s only the adorners having the issue. Will try it out over the weekend.